# How much information can I store in IndexedDB?

Tags: browser, indexeddb, web-storage

I've been searching but couldn't find an updated answer to 2022: what is the maximum size I can store in IndexedDB?

Answer (score 0):

In browsers that support it, `navigator.storage.estimate()` will return an estimation of the quota usage and quota available to the calling site.

Note that browsers have very different approaches to how much storage they permit a site to store - from very limited amounts to most of the free disk space. They may also vary the amount based on heuristics such as engagement, or vary between modes e.g. private browsing vs. normal browsing.